# Unable to Zip a File in Buffer

Tags: python, zip

i Want to Zip the CSV File in (Buffer) Using `zipFile` in Python

Below is My Code Which I Have Tried And Error Log Attached

```
I Dont want to use the compression in df.to_csv due to Version issue
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
import zipfile
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
s_buf = io.StringIO()
df.to_csv(s_buf,index=False)
s_buf.seek(0)
s_buf.name = 'my_filename.csv'
localfile= io.BytesIO()
localzip = io.BytesIO()
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(localzip, mode="w",compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zf.writestr(localfile, s_buf.read())
zf.close()
with open("D:/my_zip.zip", "wb") as f:
    f.write(zf.getvalue())
```

Error I am Getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Window/PycharmProjects/dfZip/dfZiptest.py", line 25, in <module>
    zf.writestr(localfile, s_buf.read())
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 1758, in writestr
    date_time=time.localtime(time.time())[:6])
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 345, in __init__
    null_byte = filename.find(chr(0))
AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
zf = zipFile.ZipFile("localzip.zip", mode="w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zf.write(filename + '.cvs', s_buf.read())
zf.close
```

What you are doing here is

1 - You initializa the path of the `ZipFile`

2 - You simply pass the name and then the file you want to be written to the archive. In your case you were passing `io.BytesIO()` as a name, which made no sense to Python, thus the error.

I would strongly advice you, to resolve any `Version` issues first, because while 'clever' solution may seem like a quick way out, they tend to rack up a terrible [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) latter, which can and will be a nightmare to deal with.

Comment: this Line wont Work as the FIle in Buffer if Use This gives Error FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'my_filename.cvs'

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a io.BytesIO() object as the first argument to ZipFile.writestr() where it expects either an archive name or a ZipInfo object.

```
zf.writestr(localfile, s_buf.read())
```

> zinfo_or_arcname is either the file name it will be given in the
>   archive, or a ZipInfo instance.

source: [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr)

Comment: I Tried Doing that Change By Giving a File Name  Now its Giving Error While Writing the Zip File

Comment: You'd need to post the error for me to provide further assistance.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sagar/PycharmProjects/dfZip/dfZiptest.py", line 16, in <module>
    f.write(zf.getvalue())
AttributeError: 'ZipFile' object has no attribute 'getvalue'

Comment: The error is pretty obvious - ZipFile instances do not have a getvalue method. I think you need to review the documentation.